# CDT macro expansion for try-catch block in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm having the same issue that is found in [this post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/446577/) on the eclipse forums, but it doesn't seem to have an answer.

Somehow CDT is set up such that it builds the code using the -fno-exceptions flag. It is making C++ code that used to compile fail to compile since the reference to the variable in the catch block is being preprocessed away. It only started to happen within the past couple weeks and I have not updated CDT.

I've looked at the build settings for CDT and haven't seen anything that looks similar to this issue. Has anyone else encountered this problem with CDT?